# 3D scatter plot with a fitted regression 3D plane in R language

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a 3D Multiple polynomial regression. I have two independent variables (area and number of bedrooms) and one dependent variable (price). Each independent variable has its own polynomial degree (the area has 3 degrees polynomial, and the number of bedrooms has 4 degrees polynomial).

So far, I was only able to plot in 3D with the package "scatterplot3d", but I was not able to create the fitted regression 3D plane in my plot.

My questions: I want to create a 3D graph with the fitted regression 3D plane and the scatter plot, which package should I use? How would the code look like to have the fitted regression 3D plane in my plot (if you have a general idea)?

Thank You for your help :)

Note : I am using r language in r studio cloud.

Comment: Following this link you can learn how to plot the 3D scatter plot with the regression plane using the package `plotly`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44322350/add-regression-plane-in-r-using-plotly/44324365#44324365

Comment: FYI, I removed the [tag:rstudio] tag, since that's about RStudio, not the R language itself. I know you're using it in the RStudio Cloud, but I doubt that your question or issue is specific to that.

Comment: Zach, this is close to *"recommend or find a book, tool, software library"* which is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It would help immensely if you provided a reproducible question, including sample data and code you've tried. The key words in MWE are *minimal* and *working*. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example using `plotPlane` from the `rockchalk` package, which uses the `persp` function "under the hood" but simplifies the details of the plotting operations. See the help for `plotPlane` (type `?plotPlane`) for details on how the function works and the wide range of options for customizing the plot.

```
library(rockchalk)

m1 = lm(mpg ~ poly(wt,2) + disp, data=mtcars)

old.par = par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar=c(1,1,1,1))

plotPlane(m1, "wt", "disp", pch=16, col=rgb(0,0,1,0.1), drawArrows=TRUE, alength=0, 
          acol="red", alty=1,alwd=1, theta=25, phi=0)
plotPlane(m1, "wt", "disp", pch=16, col=rgb(0,0,1,0.1), drawArrows=TRUE, alength=0, 
          acol="red", alty=1,alwd=1, theta=35, phi=20)
```

[image]

If you have more than two dependent variables in the model, `plotPlane` will set the additional variables (the ones not being plotted) to their mean (for numeric variables) or mode (for factors). For example:

```
m2 = lm(mpg ~ poly(wt,2) + disp + poly(hp,2) + poly(wt,2), data=mtcars)

plotPlane(m2, "wt", "disp", pch=16, col=rgb(0,0,1,0.1), drawArrows=TRUE, alength=0, 
          acol="red", alty=1,alwd=1, theta=25, phi=0)
plotPlane(m2, "wt", "disp", pch=16, col=rgb(0,0,1,0.1), drawArrows=TRUE, alength=0, 
          acol="red", alty=1,alwd=1, theta=35, phi=20)
```

[image]

```
# Reset graphical parameters back to defaults
par(old.par)
```