# How to add Planes in a 3D Scatter Plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, plotly-python

Using Blender created this model

[image: Blender octant cube]

that can be seen in A-frame in [this link](https://xr.tiagoperes.eu/octant.html)

[image: A-frame cctant cube]

This model is great and it gives an overview of what I'm trying to accomplish here. Basically, instead of having the names, I'd have dots that symbolize one specific platform.

The best way to achieve it with current state of the art, at my sight, is through [Plotly 3D Scatter Plots](https://plotly.com/python/3d-scatter-plots/). I've got the following scatterplot

[image: 3D scatterplot]

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tiago-peres/immersion/master/Platforms_dataset.csv')
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='Functionality ', y='Accessibility', z='Immersion', color='Platforms')
fig.show()
```

that by going to [this link](https://github.com/tiago-peres/immersion/blob/master/platforms.ipynb) you'll be able to click a button and open it in Colab

[image: GitHub open in Colab]

This nearly looks like the model. Yet, still in need to add three planes to the plot in specific locations. More precisely, in x=?, y=? and z=? (I'm using question mark because the value can be anything stablished).

In other words, want to add three planes to that scatterplot

- x = 10
- y = 30
- z = 40

In the documentation, what closely resembles what I want was [3D Surface Plots](https://plotly.com/python/3d-surface-plots/).

I've done research and found two similar questions with R

- [Insert 2D plane into a 3D Plotly scatter plot in R](https://community.plotly.com/t/insert-2d-plane-into-a-3d-plotly-scatter-plot-in-r/30833/6)
- [Add Regression Plane to 3d Scatter Plot in Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38533046/5675325)

Comment: If you're interested in this question, then you might like as well [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62620959/5675325) which was done a few days after taking into account improvements made here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the `add_trace` function in `plotly` so you can just create the surfaces and then add them to the figure:

Also, note, there's definitely ways to simplify this code, but for a general idea:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np


fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='Functionality ', y='Accessibility', z='Immersion', color='Platforms')

bright_blue = [[0, '#7DF9FF'], [1, '#7DF9FF']]
bright_pink = [[0, '#FF007F'], [1, '#FF007F']]
light_yellow = [[0, '#FFDB58'], [1, '#FFDB58']]

# need to add starting point of 0 to each dimension so the plane extends all the way out
zero_pt = pd.Series([0])
z = zero_pt.append(df['Immersion'], ignore_index = True).reset_index(drop = True)
y = zero_pt.append(df['Accessibility'], ignore_index = True).reset_index(drop = True)
x = zero_pt.append(df['Functionality '], ignore_index = True).reset_index(drop = True)

length_data = len(z)
z_plane_pos = 40*np.ones((length_data,length_data))

fig.add_trace(go.Surface(x=x, y=y, z=z_plane_pos, colorscale=light_yellow,  showscale=False))
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(x=x.apply(lambda x: 10), y=y, z = np.array([z]*length_data), colorscale= bright_blue, showscale=False))
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(x=x, y= y.apply(lambda x: 30), z =  np.array([z]*length_data).transpose(), colorscale=bright_pink, showscale=False))
```

[image]

Comment: `pd.Series.append` is deprecated, use `pd.concat([zero_pt, df["Immersion"]], ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)` instead